# neo4j UNWIND CREATE Expected n to be a map

Tags: neo4j

Using UNWIND to create multiple nodes in neo4j 2.3 I run into 'Expected n to be a map'.  In the neo4j-shell, processing a single map works:

```
neo4j-sh (?)$ export key={name:'foo'}
neo4j-sh (?)$ create (n:test) set n={key};
Nodes created: 1
```

But with UNWIND on an array I get:

```
neo4j-sh (?)$ export keys=[{name:'foo'}]
neo4j-sh (?)$ unwind {keys} as key create (n:test) set n=key;
WARNING: Expected n to be a map, but it was :`{"name":"foo"}`
```

Same happens when I call via REST.  I'm guessing it's something to do with neo4j handling parameters.  What's the correct way to feed this?

Comment: I wonder if it's being set to something like the string "{name:'foo'}".  I've never used the `export` command before, maybe it doesn't support making `Maps`.  What does your REST request body look like?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, it could be parameters.  That is a bit weird.  What if you tried this:

```
WITH {keys} AS keys
UNWIND keys as key
CREATE (n:test) SET n=key;
```

Comment: It seems to give the same result:   `WITH {keys} AS keys unwind keys as k create (n:test) set n=k return n;
WARNING: Expected n to be a map, but it was :\`{"name":"foo"}\``